# Hidden folders in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, jetbrains-ide

I have a hidden folder `/.idea` from the IDE that I want to ignore. I have followed the patter of https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore but it is not being ignored.

```
// .gitignore

# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
package-lock.json
**/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# Things that I have tried
.idea/
/.idea/
.idea/**
```

What would be the way to ignore it?

Comment: Did you already committed it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already commited your `.idea` folder you need to remove it from git index

```
git rm --cached -r .idea
```

The correct way to ignore a folder inside your `.gitignore` file is the following

```
.idea/
```